# Android studio error cannot resolve symbol 'ArrayAdapter'

Tags: android, android-activity, android-arrayadapter

i'm working on an android project and i'm facing this error when trying to use ArrayAdapter for a ListView.

I used it before in another project and it worked fine, but now even it that project I get the same error

The error says

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'ArrayAdapter'
```

I've tried to re-import the ArrayAdapter, cleaning, re-building the project but nothing work.

Hope someone will help me, thanks in advance.

```
package example.com.museum.controller;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import example.com.museum.R;
import example.com.museum.bean.Trajet;
import example.com.museum.crud.TrajetDAO;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class MyVisitActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
private ListView listView;
private List<Trajet> listMuseum;
private TrajetDAO trajetDAO;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_visit_activity);

    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("UserInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    trajetDAO = new TrajetDAO(this);
    listMuseum = new ArrayList<>();
    listView = findViewById(R.id.lvMuseum);

    try {
        trajetDAO.open();
        try {
            listMuseum = trajetDAO.getVisitByUser(sharedpreferences.getString("user_login","Unknow"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Erreur lors de la récupération de la liste", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Ouverture de la BDD","Impossible d'ouvrir la BDD");
        Toast.makeText(this, "INTERNAL ERROR!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }finally {
        trajetDAO.close();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<Trajet> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Trajet>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listMuseum);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Comment: if you've done the clean-and-rebuild routine already, can you show the stacktrace?
Or try "Invalidate Cache and Restart" in "File" menu?

Comment: There is nothing show in the log, everything is okay after the clean-and-rebuild. "Invalidate cache and restart" doesn't work either. I still have the ArrayAdapter in red

Comment: can you share the class code? or maybe project code?

Comment: the ArrayAdapter class code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOW I SOLVED IT:

Just need to reset Android Studio: Just go to C:\Users\yourusername\androidStudio3.2 (or similar) and delete this directory.

This guy shows you exactly how to do it in his video in an older version: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AwZEliSPGwU&t

Answer (score 1):

select build from the android studio toolbar, clean project and then rebuild